# P-N Junction current calculations

Tags: current

Could someone please help me to get a better understanding as to how to calculate the current flowing through the resistor and the voltage drop across the silicon diode with the assumption that the silicon diode has a forward-biased junction potential of 0.7V

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is actually rather simple, given your assumption. We can apply kirchoff's voltage law, which states that the sum of the voltages around a loop equals zero.
$$V_{in} - V_R - V_D = 0$$
With \$V_{R}\$ The voltage over the resistor, \$V_{D}\$ voltage over the diode and \$V_{in}\$ the voltage you apply to the circuit. Solving for \$V_{R}\$:
$$V_R = V_{in} - V_D = V_{in} - 0.7$$
Simply fill this in in Ohm's law:
$$I = V_R / R = (V_{in} - 0.7)/R$$
Edit : This formula is only valid when \$V_{in} > 0.7V\$ as Warren said in the comments. A voltage lower than that would not induce any negative current. (Assuming an ideal diode)

Comment: You have missed the case when Vin is less than 0.7V in which case the current will be zero. Your formula suggests that if Vin were zero current would be flowing in the other direction and we all know diodes don't do that (ignoring leakage, reverse recovery, etc.)

Comment: @OlinLathrop: In the question it was specifically said that he assumed there is a voltage drop of 700mV across the diode.

Comment: @WarrenHill That's true, I'll edit that in. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I see that now.  I hadn't read that far into the question.

Comment: I'm getting more confused here as where to start?????

Comment: I calculated the voltage drop of the diode as 9.3V and the current flowing through the resistor as 6.2A

Would this be correct??

Comment: The voltage drop across the diode is equal to 0.7V, as you assumed in your question. What voltage do you apply across the circuit?

Comment: @John: No. Your question says the voltage drop acress the diode is 0.7V. That's what *"forward biased junction potential"* means.

Comment: It is a total of 10V so I'm subtracting 0.7v from 10 so this works out to 9.3V. them 9.3/1.5 = 6.2 ??

Comment: You say "the sum of the voltages around a loop equals zero", then you follow it with a difference of voltages. Confusing.

Comment: @johnbrendan Resistor is `1.5k Ohms`, so, if you apply 10V to the circuit, you get `I=6.2mA`. Pay close attention to the units and their multipliers.